# security of arrays in annotation

Tags: java, security, annotations

I'm writing a soft that process some annotations. One of annotation's parameters is an array. One object finds this array and pass it to another object to process it. And then findbugs starts to scream that I'm passing a private array that may be mutated by malicious code. so the question is: is that true? can annotation parameters be changed in runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays returned through reflection should be a fresh copy every time they are retrieved, so there's no problem.

From a mobile code, or in general code quality, perspective you should expect an array returned or passed as an argument to an untrusted method to be malicious modified. Similarly on the receiver side of things, arrays passed as parameters or returned from callbacks may be malicious modified later. So there arrays need to be copied before handing them out and also as they are received (even before any validation).

@fge mention `List`s. When sending these out, an unmodifiable collection cannot be modified by the receiver. Receiving collections is a little more tricky. Obviously taking an untrusted `List` and wrapping it with `unmodifiableList` wont work. `new ArrayList<>(things)` is the way to go. Don't attempt to `clone` a malicious `ArrayList` because you cannot be sure what `clone` actually does.

Obviously, if you have an array of mutable objects, both the array and elements will need to be copied.

Answer (score 2):

This is true: you pass a reference to an array, and arrays are mutable. The callee can modify this array.

Your best course of action is to pass a copy of that array to the callee instead of the original array, for instance by using `Arrays.copyOf()`.

Alternatively, instead of an array, you may want to return a `List` instead and use the `Collections.unmodifiableList()` wrapper since this will avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: All arrays in Java have a `clone()` method which throws no exceptions and which needs no casting, since it returns the same type as the original array.  No need for `Arrays.copyOf`, unless you need an array of a different size.

Comment: With the drawback that it requires that array elements correctly implement `Cloneable`...

Comment: Not true.  The array is cloned, but its elements are not.  It's like `new ArrayList(existingList)`.

Comment: Ah OK, I though it was a "deep copy".